# Is modernizr.js still useful?

Tags: javascript, css, html

**I'm not looking for opinions but technical arguments to form my opinion. I know some people can't understand the difference, but it's a matter related to other proffesional area.**

I'm trying to actualize my knowledge about HTML5 AND I'd like to know if modernizr.js is still useful to solve some client cravings. I'm reading material about HTML5, but the newest that talks about modernizr.js was published 3 years ago. I didn't find info in modernizr site newer than April 2013, neither a useful clearly actualized article published this year.

I'll appreciate any help.

Actualization:

No, there are no info actualized about what I'm looking for. Just tools to test, one by one, the elements modernizr tests. I have tested some elements listed in modernizr site. Every one is, at this day, supported by the browsers, so modernizr is not necessary for them. I'll check each element in order to decide if modernizr still could help or is dead.

Special thanks to **ferr**.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that "the newest HTML5 material" was published 3 years ago, so maybe you need better search techniques. Even so, I'd say that its general domain of problem-solving is still useful.

Comment: Take a look at this [bar chart](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201403-201503-bar) still nearly 5% of people using IE 8. Modernizr.js still should be used.

Comment: no. please everyone, stop enabling browser negligence or web cruft will never erode.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as Off-Topic, because it is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Katana314. HTML5 is not the problem. I didn't find actualized info about modernizr,js. I'm pretty sure you know that the date of the publication doesn't mean that the info is actualized, and what I have found about modernizr seems to be a copy/paste of the "old" info. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks TylerH. I´m not looking for opinions, but technical data.

Comment: @Sergio: If still interested, I think if reworded, it can be a valid question in 2018. Given most browsers are evergreen and ignoring IE 11 for a minute (Chrome is arguably way more significant that IE 11), some may be confused on whether to use modernizr, use vanilla JavaScript to do feature-detection or assume all browsers have all features given a highly evergreen world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your users. Modernizr is meant to help you determine if you can use functionality that may be missing from some browsers and found in more modern browsers. If your users could possibly be using browsers that do not have functionality that you plan to use, and Modernizr is capable of helping you fill in that gap, then Modernizr is still useful to you.

Comment: Thanks, ferr. I know how it works. What I don´t know is the actual state of the modern browsers. Are them supporting today the features modernzr tests? Seems that I must read every browser "support list".

Comment: @Sergio You can't assume that your users are all on modern browsers. So, if in your environment that's a concern, Modernizr is still very useful. As far as the state of modern browsers, there are definitely feature variations from vendor to vendor even today. You can use the site caniuse.com to check compliances.

Comment: So, I must check one by one. I prefer to use fully supported elements, but I have a great client that loves to "push" the balls. Testing some elements in the site you have mentioned, seems that modernizr is not as necessary as a couple of years ago. Many thanks.